# Creating two expandable menus Android Java

Tags: java, android, menu, material-design

I've created two expandable menus in my application but seem to have messed up somewhere. Each menu displays duplicate content when they should each have their own list content.

Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
String names[] = Constant.name;
String subNames[] = Constant.subNameRecoveryTools = 
Constant.subNameAdmissions;

private List<TitleMenu> getList() {
    List<TitleMenu> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        List<SubTitle> subTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < subNames.length; j++) {
            SubTitle subTitle = new SubTitle(subNames[j]);
            subTitles.add(subTitle);
        }
        TitleMenu model = new TitleMenu(names[i], subTitles, null);
        list.add(model);
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Constant.java**

```
public class Constant {

public static String [] name = {"Recovery Tools", "Admissions"};
public static String [] subNameRecoveryTools = {"Withdrawal Scales", "Shame Scale", "Drinking Limits", "Worksheets", "eBooks"};
public static String [] subNameAdmissions = {"Pre_Screen", "Intake Paperwork", "Client Handbook", "Meet your Therapist"};
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what is your question, also include the error that you are getting and any pertinent information to duplicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go throught this link. Hope it helps you. 
https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/